# C#: Ask User for a Password which is then stored in a SecureString

Tags: c#, .net, passwords, securestring

In the small application that I'm currently developing for a customer I need to ask the user for his windows login username, password and domain and then use those with **System.Diagnostics.Process.Start** to start an application.

I have a textbox with UseSystemPasswordChar to mask the entered password.

I need a **System.Security.SecureString** to feed the password to **System.Diagnostics.Process.Start**.

How do I convert the entered text to secure string while not doing it one character after another? Alternatively: Is there a better window control to ask the user for a password that returns the entered text as SecureString?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try looking at the [SecurePasswordTextBox](http://weblogs.asp.net/pglavich/archive/2006/02/26/439077.aspx) custom control. Are you trying to do something similar to a "Run As" type command where you are trying to run the process as a different user than the one currently logged on? If not, you should be able to just call Process.Start and let it pick up the current users credentials.

Also, take a look at the following resources as well:

- [CredUIPromptForCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375177.aspx)
- [CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375178(VS.85).aspx) (Vista and Server 2008)
- [Microsoft Support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/180548)
- [LogonUser Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378184.aspx)
- [LogonUserEx Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378189(VS.85).aspx)
- [CreateProcessAsUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682429(VS.85).aspx)
- [CreateProcessWithLogonW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682431(VS.85).aspx)
- [CreateProcessWithTokenW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682434(VS.85).aspx)

The best option would probably be to use some interop p/inovke code to call CredUIPromptForCredentials to display the standard Windows dialog box and then use that information to either call Process.Start, or, more likely, call the CreateProcessAsUser function.

Comment: That's exactly what the customer wants: A minimalistic program that allows the user to start applications in their user context without logging off the currently logged in user.

Comment: can't they just shift-right click the application and select 'run as..'?

Comment: @John: As best as I can tell, "Run as..." no longer exists in Vista. You only have a "Run as Administrator" option.

Comment: @John: As long as they pay me I don't care what they could or could not do :)

Answer (score 3):

The reason the SecureString wants to accept one character at a time is that otherwise you would have the entire string before that and cause the string to be in memory. Thus, using a SecureString in this scenario kind of defeats the purpose.